# mapserver how to get rid of unknown character from label

Tags: mapserver, labeling, openscales, encoding, internationalization

I am developing a gis system using mapserver and open scales library. GIS data is taken from a shape file. When i try to show the name attached to a place its showing unknown characters (not in english) along with its name in english. 
here is my .map file settings

```
 LAYER
   NAME city
   TYPE POINT
   STATUS ON      
   LABELITEM 'NAME'         
   MAXSCALE 7500000
  DATA "ndia_location.shp"   

 CLASS
   EXPRESSION ( '[PLACE]'=='city' )

    LABEL           
            COLOR 0 0 0
            TYPE BITMAP
            SIZE SMALL          
            POSITION CC
        #MINFEATURESIZE 100
        ENCODING UTF-8
            PARTIALS FALSE
        BUFFER 0
        END
      END
```

Is there a  way to show only English name for the label.
I have tried with openlayers javascript library also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For labeling you should use appropriate font which contained needed characters.

Create fonts.list file with the simmilar content:

```
# This be the fonts list
arial    arial.ttf
tahoma   tahoma.ttf
symbols  symbols.ttf
```

and put described fonts in the same directory. In MAP section of mapfile points to fonts.list:

```
MAP    
    FONTSET     "fonts/fonts.list"
```

And in LABEL section set needed font:

```
LABEL
        FONT "tahoma"
        TYPE TRUETYPE
```

Comment: how do i know which font to use?.I use ogrinfo command in linux to get the details about features in the shapefile. But its not giving any info about the font used

Comment: First of all you should to determine encoding of your shapefile attribute data and point it within LABEL section, also you should set appropriate font which contains needed characters. For more information see http://mapserver.org/mapfile/labelencoding.html#labelencoding